# Codeiginter file Session.php does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that is a problem which have been answerd hundred times, but nothing works for me. When i upload web page on server i'm keep getting error `The configuration file Session.php does not exist.`

This is my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';//enable session with db
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//database table name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['encryption_key'] = 'pXeQY2733rR560MrwJy40OL4WaSGmr5A';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myapp.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My autoload file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'form_validation', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form');
```

Sql which i used for mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

[image]

So far i have tried/added 
 1. Change auto load session in to the Session
 
 2. All controllers and models files/class names start with upper case
 3. Added encryption_key

What else can i do guys? If you need any additional informations please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Unix/Linux, make sure to load your library with capital letters:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('Session');`

If nothing works, download again and reinstall from new pack

`http://www.codeigniter.com/download`